# Disallow URLs that contain a directory

Tags: robots.txt

I have URLs which appear like so:

```
www.website.com/user/1
www.website.com/user/2
www.website.com/user/3
```

As you can see, they all contain `/user/` and then a number. How can I disallow URLs like this in my robots.txt? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your robots.txt

```
Disallow: /user/
```